# ncurses screen/tmux-256color

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, colors, ncurses

I have my term set to `tmux-256color` through `.tmux.conf`, but I can't get 256 color mode in an ncurses app working. According to this [post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Talk:Tmux#New_Tmux_terminfo) it should be supported by now. `xterm-256color` works perfectly fine.

Running the app with:

```
 env TERM=tmux-256color ./ncurses_app
```

doesn't work either. The same is true for screen-256color.

CMAKE Script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(pkgsinfo)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE  on)
set(SOURCE_FILES
   ProjectFiles.c)

set(CURSES_NEED_WIDE ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake/Modules")
find_package(Curses 6 EXACT REQUIRED)
add_executable(pkgsinfo ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(pkgsinfo ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

The link arguments for this project:

```
/usr/bin/cc -g   CMakeFiles/pkgsinfo.dir/ProjectFiles.c.o -o 
pkgsinfo /usr/lib/libncursesw.so /usr/lib/libtinfo.so -lform
```

It's using the wide library. Also screen-256color and tmux-256color are installed in the terminfo database.

Is full support for tmux and screen 256color still not in?

Comment: The question doesn't say how/why you see it's not working :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's rather vague: either the terminal entry is installed, or it's not.  Systems (such as Debian and those derived from it such as Ubuntu) which default to a "small" terminal database don't install any of the *tmux* variants.

If you set `TERM` to something that is not installed, both screen and tmux will give an error and stop.  ncurses applications calling `initscr` also will give an error, and stop.

When using 256-colors, you would need ncurses6 and use the wide-character library, e.g., `-lncursesw` since the narrow (`-lncurses`) library supports only up to 16 colors.